# Tomcat, Java & Oracle9. org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, tomcat7

I am using Tomcat and Java (through Eclipse) and Oracle Database 9.2.1

I am getting

```
org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.sql.SQLException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver
(PooledConnection.java:243)
```

My code is

**context.xml**

```
<Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource" auth="Container"
name="jdbc/charmDB"
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:db"
username="db" password="db" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"  
/>

<Resource name="jdbc/charmDB" auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
description="My Database"/>
```

**Java code**

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/charmDB");
Connection con = ds.getConnection();
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your context.xml appears to have two resources with the same name: jdbc/charmDB.

Try resolving this issue first.

EDIT: Make sure your Oracle JDBC driver jar is in the Tomcat lib directory.

Comment: I removed the second resource.  However I am still getting the same error!

Comment: I added a Tomcat 7 tag. Maybe someone using the new connection pooling library have seen this error before.

Comment: Check that the driver is in the Tomcat's lib dir.

Comment: Thank you.  I was indeed missing the Oracle JDBC driver Jar.  [In order to add this to a Tomcat Instance when using Eclipse, then one needs to double-click the server, and then select "Open Launch Configuration." One then clicks "ClassPath" and then "Add External JARS"]